# Center the angular MatDialog

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have implemented a modal dialog using angular MatDialog to be used in place of the alert() function.
Everything works fine but the positioning of the dialog. I can't manage to place the dialog at the center of the page. The dialog always appears at the bottom left edge of the page.

The html file looks as follows:

```
<h2>Oups! Something went wrong.</h2>

<p>{{error}}</p>

<button class="btn-outline-primary" mat-dialog-close>OK</button>
```

And this the function to open the dialog

```
private openDialog(error: string) {
const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

dialogConfig.data = {
  error: 'This is a test'
}
dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
dialogConfig.hasBackdrop = false;
dialogConfig.autoFocus = false;
dialogConfig.width = '600px';
dialogConfig.height = '200px';

this.dialog.open(ErrorDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```

And the component class:

```
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from "@angular/material";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-error-dialog',
  templateUrl: './error-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./error-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class ErrorDialogComponent  {
 error: string;

 constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data) {
  this.error = data.error;
 }
}
```

Here a screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Did you include material css to your project yet?

Comment: What do you mean @Robin? The Dialog is an Angular component with an empty css file.

Comment: Have you added theme in your style.css if not `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` add this and try

Comment: @edmond You have to include material design css from `@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css` to apply css rules.

Comment: Adding `@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` does solve the problem. Awesome. Thanks to @Vikas.

Answer (score 0):

This code in any component where you want to open a dialog. You must have a reference to MatDialog. The mdRef is the instance of the object after opening.

```
// getConfig returns a matDialogConfig with the data
mc = this.getConfig(data);
// Tell Matdialog which Angular component to use.
mdRef = this.md.open(MessageComponent, mc);
```

The MessageComponent

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from "@angular/material/dialog";
    import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, Inject } from "@angular/core";
    import { inject } from "@angular/core/testing";

    @Component({
      selector: "lib-message",
      templateUrl: "./message.component.html",
      styleUrls: ["./message.component.css"],
    })
    export class MessageComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
      constructor(@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {
        // get the injected dialog data
        this.data = data;
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {}
      ngAfterViewInit() {}
    }
```

And the css

```
 :host {
        display: grid;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background-color: yellow;
        position: absolute;
        top: 10em;
        left: 20em;
        height: 10em;
        width: 20em;
        box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.27);
    }
```

Summary: The message component's css overrides the cdkOverlay default settings!

Comment: Did this help you?